# Once input completed on one page, a second page loads with input showing in relevant fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

I thought a basic (I mean basic) example of what I want to do would help with this. What I want to have happen is either have page A once completed load page B or page B loads over top page A with the input showing. I need to be able to do this without JQuery or PHP, so will be working with HTML, CSS and pure Javascript.

```
Page A  (Form to fill in)
<html>

Name:<input type='text' ID="name" name='Name' />
Reference: <input type='text' ID="reference" name='reference' />
Address : <textarea name="Customers Address" ID="custadd" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
Item not received? <select>
    <option value="0" ></option>
    <option value="1" >Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No</option>
</select>

<input type="button" Transfers input on this page into fields on prinatble form>

</html>

Page B (Output printable form)

<html>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>
Name:
</td>
<td>
*(name appears here)*
</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
Reference:
</td>
<td>
*(Reference goes here)*
</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
Address :
</td>
<td>
*(address goes here)*
</td>
<td>
Item not received?
</td>
<td>
*(Yes/no here)*
<style>
<style>

#myTable {

  border: none;;
font color:#000000
  font-size: 16px;
```

Comment: Put one page A in one div and another page B in another div. Till page A is complete, keep page B div hidden. So both will be in the same page, may be same form but visible only after one part is complete.